# What does object file look like

Tags: c++, c

As i know
.c source goes to assembly then it goes to object file, object files then are linking to each other(and to libraries) and we get application we can run from os.
But what does object file look like?
Does it look like .asm or more like .exe?
**How are instructions inside object file stored? As** "mov add call" **pseudocode or as machine senseless code?** (is the question)

Comment: As machine code. With very little alterations, if any, the processor the code was compiled for can "understand" the contents of the object file.

Comment: There are many different flavors of object files, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine code. You can use `gcc -S` to get assembly and `gcc -c` to get object files.

Comment: I see  options: 1)-S Compile only; do not assemble or link and 2)-c Compile and assemble, but do not link. So compile means .c to asm and asemble means asm to obj?

Comment: Also, -o is not for "object file", it is for output file, which could be either object or executable.

Answer (score 3):

Object files have some symbol information (usually proprietary, compiler/linker dependent) and the raw compiled machine code ready to be executed.

ELF (Executable and Linkable format) used in Linux and many other systems goes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try **objdump** command on Linux system to display information about object files like:

```
objdump -D <filename.o> | more
```

Answer (score 1):

Object files are machine code for the specific processor targeted by the compiler, along with symbolic information like function names in the case of libraries so that runtime-linked code can find the memory location (within the object file) of executable code.

Ooh @hexa gave a much nicer answer while I was logging in : )